# Too many Local Variables and Stack Base Pointer Offset Overflows

Tags: c, assembly, x86

So the %ebp (stack base pointer) + a constant is used to reference local variables in assembly. What if there are too many local variables and the required constant is soo large that it does not fit in one line of assembly code (32 or 64 bits)? How are edge cases like this handled?

[image: ebp reference]

For example, in the above image assume that there are 2^30 local variables. To reference the last one we would need an offset of 2^32. If we are working in a 32bit environment this offset won't fit in one line of code considering there is the opcode, destination etc also in that same line.

Comment: You won't have that much stack anyway so you would get, wait for it, a stack overflow! \o/ But if you did have enough, it would just wrap around.

Comment: Realistically, the compiler will blow up long before that (so it never even has the chance to generate asm code that would have this problem), since that AST and other internal data structures would be even bigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In its 32 bit and 64 bit operation modes, the x86 architecture addressing modes allow for either no displacement, an 8 bit displacement, or a 32 bit displacement.

In 32 bit mode, a 32 bit displacement is sufficient to describe every possible displacement (and thus, every possible stack offset). For your concern: The stack couldn't possibly contain 2<sup>30</sup> variables as that would be 4 GiB of stack space, leaving no space to store the machine code.

In 64 bit mode, it is indeed possible to have displacements that cannot be described with a 32 bit displacement. This rarely happens in reality (which is why the AMD engineers decided to leave the displacement size at 32 bit) but it can happen occasionally. In such cases, the displacement has to be applied through a register:

```
mov rax,0x123456789abcdef0 ; displacement
mov eax,[rax,rbp]          ; value
```